# How to cache file in order to not reading it in every search iteration?

Tags: java, algorithm, file, search

I am implementing an algorithm that will search in a csv file for a string that has a column with a prefix entered by the user. After finding the first search result, the user can enter a different prefix to perform a second search. The column number is specified only once, and only the prefix is allowed to be changed during the subsequent search. This will continue until the user enters "end".

**Example of search:**

**File Data:**

```
1, "Adam", "Computer Science"
2, "Liza", "Condensed Matter Physics"
3, "Bob", "Electrochemistry"
4, "Eva", "Material Culture"
```

**Search parameters:**

```
column: 3, prefix: "Co"
```

**Search result:**

```
1, "Adam", "Computer Science"
2, "Liza", "Condensed Matter Physics"
```

**My algorithm must meet specific conditions:**

- not reading all lines from file at each search
- not store all file data in memory (dont matter if it is bytes array or any other structure which contains all file data)
- not edit file and not create other files (also not use db)

It turns out that with each search operation we have to process the entire file, because any string in file can have the specified prefix. How can this be implemented without violating the above conditions? Maybe you know algorithm that can be used in this case?

According to my guesses, we will need to process the entire file anyway. This means either reading all the lines from it at each search, or storing it completely in memory in order to exclude access to the file and work with this structure. Both of these options violate the condition of the problem.

Comment: *search in a csv file for a string that has a column with a prefix entered by the user* is not a very clear requirement. Can you provide example input/output?

Comment: It sounds like sorting the rows ahead of the search could solve the problem if you are allowed to handle the stored data. Either that or creating some index.

Comment: @shmosel, question updated, added example

Comment: @ODDminus1, unforunately it is not available to edit stored data.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Does "not reading all lines from file" imply that we may repeatedly read parts of the file? Also, is the column only specified once?

Comment: Okay, but creating an index which only stores the column which you are querying and a reference to the line number in the csv should be a solution which meets the criteria. E.g. `Map<String, List<Integer>>` which holds all the line numbers for a searchable value. Then you only need to build the map by reading the full file once, and you can later find the values in the map to find a narrow way to query the csv.

Comment: @ODDminus1: If you create such an index for each column (which you need to allow searches for each column) you practically stored all data of the file in memory.

Comment: If the prefix is "Ma", will that match rows 2 and 4, or just 4?

Comment: @shmosel, the column number is specified once, only the prefix changes during the subsequent search. The algorithm can read some blocks of the file repeatedly, the main condition is not to read the whole file.

Comment: @MrSmith42 you can exclude all columns which isn't a part of the index, and if the search term is just for a prefix of a maximum certain size, you are saving some data there as well. With the given example, you aren't really saving anything, but with a larger csv, this could become significant. At any cost, it fits the criteria of not storing all the data.

Comment: @ODDminus1, we will have to fill in the Map for each prefix, which means going through the entire file again.  E.g. for the first search we filled Map for one prefix, now we can go through this map to find suitable lines from file. But if search again for another prefix we will have to read all file again, to find suitable line numbers for this prefix and put it in the Map. So for every search we will read all file again. Did I understand your solution correctly?

Comment: @user3386109, prefix "Ma" will only match row 4.

Comment: @ODDminus1, I think that the only correct solution to this problem may be the answer proposed by icelop, in which a cache of a certain size is used. This cache will be updated with each search (the Least Recently Used or a Fixed-Size cache). In this case, we really won't store the whole file, but only part of it. And also we will not read the entire file again, because some part of it will already be stored in memory.

Comment: Row count = cache size. Row's column value = cache entry (key-value pair of row number and column value). Then, for searching use some data structure like Trie.

Comment: @Ymrik, is the prefix of a set maximum size, or could it be any length - potentially the entire string? If the former, I could throw together an answer with some code examples.

Comment: Then you can hack the requirements by loading half the file into memory and reading half from disk. But I don't imagine that's the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an index that maps each value in the specified column to its line offset in the file, and then jump to the line using `RandomAccessFile`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("File: ");
    String path = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Column: ");
    int col = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    Map<Long, String> index = index(path, col);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Prefix: ");
        String prefix = in.nextLine();
        if (prefix.equals("end")) {
            return;
        }

        try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r")) {
            for (Map.Entry<Long, String> line : index.entrySet()) {
                if (line.getValue().startsWith(prefix)) {
                    file.seek(line.getKey());
                    System.out.println(file.readLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Map<Long, String> index(String file, int col) throws IOException {
    Map<Long, String> index = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    long offset = 0;
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file))) {
        String value = line.split(",")[col - 1]
                .replaceAll("^ *\"|\" *$", "");
        index.put(offset, value);
        offset += line.length() + System.lineSeparator().length();
    }
    return index;
}
```

To keep things simple, I took the liberty of assuming lines don't contain nested quotes or commas and that we're using the system line separator. But feel free to adjust as necessary.

Also note that the map is not really a map so much as a list of entries. The column is stored as the value in case it contains duplicates. `Map` isn't designed for prefix searching anyway, but it shouldn't matter much unless you're dealing with huge files. You can optimize with a trie if necessary, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an index of three-letter prefixes for the selected column. There are only 17576 three-letter prefixes (ignoring case) so the index would have 17576 entries.
Each entry in the index would be a list of offsets into the file for the lines that match the prefix.

For example, if the file contains this:

| Line from the file | Offset into the file |
| --- | --- |
| 1,"Sara","Common Algorithms" | 0 |
| 2,"Adam","Computer Science" | 29 |
| 3,"Liza","Condensed Matter Physics" | 57 |
| 4,"Bob","Electrochemistry" | 93 |
| 5,"Eva","Material Culture" | 120 |

Then the index would contain this:

| prefix | offsets |
| --- | --- |
| "Com" | 0, 29 |
| "Con" | 57 |
| "Ele" | 93 |
| "Mat" | 120 |

This is a variation on a [set-associative cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_placement_policies#Set-associative_cache) where the three-letter prefix is the set identifier, and the file offsets are the data. The cache can be implemented as a dictionary where the key is the prefix, and the value is a list of file offsets.

When the search request contains a three-letter prefix, simply get the list for that prefix from the cache, seek to each offset in the file, and read the line.

When the search request contains a two-letter prefix, it matches up to 26 three-letter prefixes. So check the dictionary for each of the possible matching three-letter prefixes, and read the lines for each of those.
For the example above, the two-letter prefix "Co" matches "Com" and "Con", so the search result contains three lines, starting at offsets 0, 29, and 57. (A one-letter prefix matches up to 676 three-letter prefixes.)

When the search request contains a four-letter (or longer) prefix, read all of the lines for the corresponding three-letter prefix, but only return those lines that match the given prefix. For the example above, the four-letter prefix "Comp" would read both lines for "Com", but only return the line `2,"Adam","Computer Science"`.